# Dimension of Holder space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, holder-spaces, dimensional-analysis

> $\textbf{Definition}$ Let $ \Omega $ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha \in (0,1]$. 
>   \begin{align*}
> \textrm{For } \alpha\in(0,1],& \newline\\
> &[u]_{\alpha,\Omega}:=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\vert u(x)-u(y) \vert}{\vert x-y \vert^{\alpha}} \quad \textrm{for } x,y\in \Omega\\
> \newline 
> &\Vert u \Vert_{C^0(\bar{\Omega})}:= \sup_{x\in \Omega} \vert u(x) \vert \\
> \newline
> &\Vert u\Vert_{C^k(\bar {\Omega})} :=\sum_{0\leq \vert \beta \vert \leq k} \Vert D^{\beta}u \Vert _{C^0(\bar{\Omega})}\\
> \newline
> &\Vert u\Vert_{C^{k,\alpha}(\bar {\Omega})}:= \Vert u \Vert_{C^k(\bar{\Omega})} + \sum_{\vert \beta \vert =k} [D^{\beta}u]_{\alpha, \Omega} 
> \end{align*}
>   $\textbf{Holder space} \quad  C^{k,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega}):=\{u\in C^{k}(\bar{\Omega}); \Vert u \Vert_{C^{k,\alpha}}(\bar{\Omega})< \infty
> \}$

I want to know whether Holder space has finite bases or not. How to find bases of Holder space??...

Any help is appreciated... Thank you!

Comment: They all contain, for example $C^{k+1}(\bar\Omega)$ or (restriction of) $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, so is never finite.

Comment: Why does $C^{k,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$ contain $C^{k+1} (\bar{\Omega})$??

Comment: If $\Omega$ is bounded, we have bounded derivative implies Lipschitz implies Hölder.  If $\Omega$ is unbounded, Hölder is actually stronger than $C^1$ or Lipschitz estimate for farapart $x,y$, so use $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ instead.

Comment: Holder spaces are between $C^0$ and $C^1$ )by interpolation) and both spaces has infinite dimension.